# Build a application form a web

Tags: c#, build

I have developed a Windows game application form C#. It contains 3 DLLs and one EXE. But one DLL is need to build time to time, because it contains an XML file and I need to change that time to time and embedded in to that DLL. After building that DLL I'm publishing and deploying though ClickOnce Deployment. For better convenient I decide to do make a separate web site to change the XML.  Now what I need to  do is that building process and publishing process do via my web application. Currently my web site and Game app in same Server. Is it possible to that building process and publishing process via my web site. Something like run in bat file in .NET command prompt? (Web site and Game developed in C# & VS2008)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just leave the xml file as an external resource if it's changing regularly?  (i.e. don't complile it into the dll)

Comment: No. i know that. but that xml need to embedded in dll and published. That is the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to be able to compile each DLL for each customer.  In effect, each customer will have their own unique DLL containing a specific XML resource.

There are ways of doing this - it's simply a matter of automating your build process.  It's not *easy* to do this but it can be done.  You might research MSBuild - it's suitable for automated compiling.

Comment: Yes, but I'm passing Same XML-DLL to all customer. once they start the application it will update automatically (becoz i used click one). My requirement is Change the XML file form My web site (Admin) and save that XML. After that in the web page there will be a button call 'Publish'. when i press that button, need to compile only that DLL and published my Game with New version no. i know i can do that from command prompt in .NET, but i don't know how to call command prompt form web and do the job remotely. currently I'm doing same process with VS IDE. but i need to do that form My web site.